# laravel schedule : clouser function is not getting called or executed

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler

Consider below is my **kernel.php**:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {

    Log::info('Testing scheduler output');
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Log::info('Testing scheduler: ' . date("d/m/Y h:i:sa"));
    });
    
  exit;
}
```

I am trying to run the scheduler by below command :

> **php artisan schedule:run**

Expected output is :

```
[current timestamp] local.INFO: Testing scheduler output
[current timestamp] local.INFO: Testing scheduler: <current_timestamp>
```

Actual output what I am getting is :

```
[current timestamp] local.INFO: Testing scheduler output
```

**I am not able to understand why closure function's log is not generated or that code is not executed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `exit;` line from the end of your `schedule` method, you don't need that.

You are registering the closure command, but Laravel is not executing it right away.

Laravel registers your schedule in the Kernel when the framework boots from console, and then the `schedule:run` console command executes those separately. You are calling `exit` before Laravel has a chance to execute tasks.

Comment: jszbody can you please provide me more details on this.....i understood bit of this

Comment: @MiteshBhanushali You are registering the closure function, but then you call `exit;` right afterwards. That kills the entire PHP execution.